# How to do 2 decimal digit approximation in C++?

Tags: c++, approximation

I would like to do approximation in my code here.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double num1 = 123.455;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << num1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**What I want:**

```
123.46
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.284 s
Press any key to continue.
```

**Actual Result:**

```
123.45
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.284 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I'm sure that I need to use `setprecision`, but what do I still need to add to successfully get the desired output?

Answer (score -3):

`#include <cmath>`

`std::round(num1*100.0)/100.0`

should do the trick.

Comment: The compiler says: error: 'round' is not a member of 'std'.

Comment: Did you include the necessary header? ``#include <cmath>``

Comment: I've figured it out, thanks!